# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to evaluate
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}}dx$$

**My attempt**

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}}dx&=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}{\ln(1+x)}d(\ln^2(1+x^2))\\ &=\frac{1}{4}(\ln(1+x)\ln^2(1+x^2)|_0^1-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^2(1+x^2)}d\ln(1+x))\\ &=\frac{1}{4}(\ln^32-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx)\\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin {align} 
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^{2}\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{1+x} d x\\=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^{2}\left(1-y^{2}\right)}{1+i y} i d y-\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\ln ^{2}\left(1+e^{i 2 \theta}\right)}{1+e^{i \theta}} i e^{i \theta} d\theta\\
=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y \ln ^{2}\left(1-y^{2}\right)}{1+y^{2}} dy+\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) \ln ^{2}(2 \cos \theta)d\theta+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \theta \ln (2 \cos \theta)d\theta\\&-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \theta^{2} \tan \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)d\theta
 \end {align}$$

> But how to evaluate
>   $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx$$

The answer from Mathematica is $$\frac{1}{96}(24\pi\mathbf{G}+\pi^2\ln2+8\ln^32-60\zeta(3))$$

$\mathbf{G}$ is Catalan's constant.

**My answer**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Integral calculator gives $0.2025784084280738$ as an approximation, it did not return a closed form.

Comment: @Paras Khosla Mathematica gives a closed form.See my edit.

Comment: Is that expression the original integral or the final one?

Comment: @J.G. It's orginal one.$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{x\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}}dx$

Comment: So just to summarise what we already know, your new integral is $$A:=\int_0^1 x^2\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n+1}\right)^2\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^n x^n\right)dx=\sum_{klm}\frac{(-1)^{k+l+m}}{(k+1)(l+1)(k+l+m+3)}.$$We want to prove $$A=\frac{2\ln^3 2}{3}-\pi G-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{24}+\frac{5\zeta(3)}{2}.$$

Comment: Do you have some idea? I think it can be divide into some parts.

Comment: It's always the same old story. Seek for the sister and stay tuned !!

Comment: See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.12155) for a systematic approach

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already used contour integration to split the integral into four parts:
$$\begin {align} 
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln ^{2}\left(1+x^{2}\right)}{1+x}dx\\
=&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x \ln ^{2}\left(1-x^{2}\right)}{1+x^{2}} dx+\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \ln ^{2}(2 \cos x)dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/2} x \ln (2 \cos x)dx\\&-\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} x^{2} \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)dx
 \end {align}$$

---

Denote those four integrals by $I_1,\cdots, I_4$. 
$$I_1 = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(x)}{2-x}dx = \text{Li}_3(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\ln^2 3}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln 2 +\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)$$
For $I_2$, tangent-half substitution gives
$$I_2 = \int_0^1\frac{2t\ln^2(2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})}{1+t^2}dt = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(2\frac{1-t}{1+t})}{1+t}dt = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (2t)}{1+t}dt = \frac{3\zeta(3)}{2}+\ln^3 2 -\frac{\pi^2}{6}\ln 2$$
where the penultimate step involves $t\mapsto (1-t)/(1+t)$.

For $I_3$, integration by part gives
$$I_3 = \int_0^{\pi/2} (\frac{\pi}{2}-x)\ln(2\sin x) dx = -\frac{\pi^2}{8}\ln 2+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2 \cot x dx $$
Use the identity
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx) = \frac{1}{2}\cot\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\cos(N+1/2)x}{2\sin(x/2)}$$
letting $N\to \infty$, and the remainder $\to 0$ by Riemann-Lebesuge lemma, so 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\cot x dx = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\sin(2nx) dx = \frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln 2 -\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}$$ Note that each summand can be evaluated explicitly. Therefore $I_3 = -7\zeta(3)/16$.

For $I_4$, use the same identity, gives
$$I_4 = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\sin[n(\pi-x)]dx = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^2\sin (nx)dx$$ the series definition of Catalan constant immediately gives
$$I_4 = 2\pi G - \frac{21\zeta(3)}{8} - \frac{\pi^2}{4}\ln 2$$

Combining all these should give you the result.

Answer (score 8):

An alternative "elementary" solution (no contour integral, no complex number actually)

Hold your breath !

\begin{align}\text{A}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 \text{B}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 \text{A+B}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(1-x^2)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=x^2$,

\begin{align}
 \text{A+B}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x }{1+x}\,dx
\end{align}

In the first and the third integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,

\begin{align}
 \text{A+B}&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{2x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x }{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
 &+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{\ln^2  2}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\\
 &\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x }{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{6}\ln^3 2-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{2}\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \text{A-B}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$

\begin{align}
 \text{A-B}&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\ln\left(\frac{2(1+x^2)}{(1+x)^2}\right)\ln x\,dx\\
 &=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx-\\
 &2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+ 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

In the second and the fourth integrals perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=x^2$,

\begin{align}
 \text{A-B}&=\frac{3}{4}\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{9}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+ 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

Define function $R$ on $[0;1]$ by:

\begin{align}R(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
 &=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{1+tx}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
 \text{C}&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\Big[R(x)\ln(1+x^2)\Big]_0^1 -\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{2x^2\ln(tx)}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}\,dt\,dx\\
 &=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{2x^2\ln t}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}\,dt\,dx-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{2x^2\ln x}{(1+tx)(1+x^2)}\,dt\,dx\\
 &=\left(\int_0^1 \frac{2t\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln t\ln(1+t)}{t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln 2) t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\right)-\\
 &\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx+\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
 &=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{t}\,dt-\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{ t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\pi\text{G}
\end{align}

(all the integrals have been computed using antiderivatives)

In the third integral perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=t^2$,

\begin{align}
 \text{C}&=\frac{3}{4}\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx-\Big[\ln^2t\ln(1+t)\Big]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\pi\text{G}\\
 &=\frac{3}{4}\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{1}{2}\pi\text{G}\\
\end{align}

Define function $S$ on $[0;1]$ by:

\begin{align}S(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\\
 &=\int_0^1 \frac{tx^2\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 \text{D}&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
 &=\Big[S(x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{tx^2\ln(tx)}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dt\,\,dx\\
 &=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{tx^2\ln t}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dt\,\,dx-\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{tx^2\ln x}{(1+t^2x^2)(1+x)}\,dt\,\,dx\\
 &=\left(\int_0^1\frac{t\ln t\ln(1+t^2)}{2(1+t^2)}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ln(1+t^2)}{2t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{(\ln 2)t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\right)-\\
 &\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx+\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
\end{align}

In the first, second, fourth, sixth integrals perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=t^2$ (or $ \displaystyle y=x^2$),

\begin{align}
 \text{D}&=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt-\frac12 \text{C}\\
 &=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{1}{16}\Big[\ln^2 t\ln(1+t)\Big]_0^1+\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt-\frac12 \text{C}\\
 &=\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt+\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt-\frac12 \text{C}\\
 \end{align}

Define function $T$ on $[0;1]$ by:

\begin{align}T(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Observe that,

\begin{align}T(0)&=0\\
T(1)`&=-\text{G}
\end{align}

\begin{align}\text{E}&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\Big[T(x)\arctan x\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\,dx\\
&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln t}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\,dx-\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\,dx\\
&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}+\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(\frac{1+t^2}{2}\right)}{1-t^2}\,dt-E\\
\end{align}

Observe that for $t\in [0;1[$,

\begin{align}\frac{1}{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{1+t}+\frac{t}{1-t^2} \end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}E&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln t\ln\left(1+t^2\right)}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\text{C}-\text{E}\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=t^2$

\begin{align}E&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac18\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(1+t\right)}{1-t}\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\text{C}-\text{E}\\
&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\frac18\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln\left(\frac{1+t}{2}\right)}{1-t}\,dt+\\
&\frac{1}{2}\text{C}-\text{E}
\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}$,

\begin{align}E&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt-\\
&\frac18\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{1+t}\right)\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln\left(1+t\right)\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\text{C}-\text{E}\\
&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\\
&\frac18\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln\left(1+t\right)}{1+t}\,dx+\frac18\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1+t\right)}{t}\,dt-\\
&\frac18\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(1+t\right)\ln\left(1-t\right)}{t}\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\text{C}-\text{E}\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1+t\right)}{t}\,dt&=\Big[\ln t\ln^2(1+t)\Big]_0^1-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt\\
F&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)\ln(1-t) }{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac12 \left(\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln^2(1-t^2) }{t^2}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-t) }{t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+t) }{t}\,dt\right)\\
\end{align}

In the first integral perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=1-t^2$,

In the second integral perform the change of variable $\displaystyle  y=1-t$,

\begin{align}F&=\frac12 \left(2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t) }{1+t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t}\,dt+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t}\,dt\right)\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t) }{1+t}\,dt-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t}\,dt\\
H&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)\ln\left(1+t\right)}{1+t}\,dt
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-t}{1+t}$,

\begin{align}H&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{2}{1+t}\right)\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=\ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}2E&=-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\\
&\frac{1}{8}\left( \ln 2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt\right)-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac18\left( \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t) }{1+t}\,dt-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t }{1-t}\,dt\right)+\frac{1}{2}\text{C}\\
E&=\frac{\text{C}}{4}-\frac{\text{G}\pi}{8}-\frac{\ln 2}{8} \int_0^1\frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{1}{64} \int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\frac14\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt \\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}D&=\frac{1}{16} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt+\frac{1}{64} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)\ln t}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac{\ln 2}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt -\frac{\text{C}}{4}-\frac{\text{G}\pi} {8}\\
&=\frac{1}{64} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\frac{3}{16} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)\ln t}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac{\ln 2}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt-\frac{3\ln 2}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
B&=\frac12\Big((A+B)-(A-B)\Big)\\
&=\frac{\ln^3 2}{12}+\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{64}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac{5}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{5\ln 2}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Since, for $t\neq 1$,

\begin{align}\frac{1}{1+t}&=\frac{1}{1-t}-\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\\
\frac{1}{1-t^2}&=\frac{1}{1-t}-\frac{t}{1-t^2}
\end{align}

then,

\begin{align}\text{B}&=\frac{\ln^3 2}{12}+\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{21}{64}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac{3\ln 2}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt+\frac{\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln t}{1-t^2}\,dt+\frac{5}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}\,dt\\
\end{align}

In the two latter integrals perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=t^2$,

\begin{align}\text{B}&=\frac{\ln^3 2}{12}+\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\\
&\frac{\ln 2}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
U&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)\ln t}{1+t}\,dt\\
W&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{t}{1+t}\right)}{1+t}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{t}{1+t}$,

\begin{align}
W&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-t}\,dt-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
\end{align}

In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-t}{t}$

\begin{align}
W&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{t(1+t)}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt-\Big[\ln t\ln^2(1+t)\Big]_0^1+2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt\\ 
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t}\,dt+2U\\
\end{align}

On the other hand,

\begin{align}
W&=\int_0^1\frac{\left(\ln t-\ln(1+t)\right)^2}{1+t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1+t)}{1+t}\,dx-2U\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
U&=\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{2t\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}\,dt
\end{align}

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=t^2$,

\begin{align}
U&=-\frac{1}{16}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}\text{B}&=\frac{\ln^3 2}{12}+\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{5}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt-\frac{\ln 2}{16}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{\ln^3 2}{12}+\frac{\text{G}\pi}{4}-\frac{5}{16}\times 2\zeta(3)-\frac{\ln 2}{16}\times -\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{1}{12}\ln^3 2+\frac{1}{4}\text{G}\pi-\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{96}\pi^2\ln 2}
\end{align}

Comment: very nice and clear +1

Comment: -1<1 and A,B,C,D,...

Answer (score 4):

I hope you won't mind my attempt to the indefinite integral using polylogarithms. **NOT AN ANSWER**

I re-wrote $\log^2(1+x^2)$ as
$$\log^2(1+ix)(1-ix)=\log^2(1+ix) + 2\log(1+ix)\log(1-ix) + \log^2(1-ix).$$
Therefore you can write
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I &=& \int\frac{\log^2(1+x^2)}{1+x}dx=\\
&=& \underbrace{\int\frac{\log^2(1+ix)}{1+x}dx}_{\mathcal I_1} + 2\underbrace{\int\frac{\log(1+ix)\log(1-ix)}{1+x}dx}_{\mathcal I_2}+\\
& &+\underbrace{\int\frac{\log^2(1-ix)}{1+x}dx}_{\mathcal I_3}\tag{*}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
I first concentrated on the integral
$$\mathcal I_1 = \int \frac{\log^2(1+ix)}{1+x}dx$$
for which I used the change of variables
$$\omega = \frac{x+1}{2} -i \frac{x+1}{2},$$
that gives
$$ x = (1+i)\omega -1,$$
$$1+ix = (1-i)(\omega + 1),$$
and
$$dx = (1+i)d\omega.$$
So we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=& \int \frac{\left[\log(1-i)+\log(1+\omega)\right]^2}{\omega}d\omega=\\
&=&\log^2(1-i)\log \omega +2\log(1-i) \text{Li}_2(-\omega) +\underbrace{\int\frac{\text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)}{\omega}d\omega}_{\mathcal A(\omega)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Integrating by parts $\mathcal A$ yields
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal A(\omega) &=& \text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)\log(-\omega) + 2\int\frac{\text{Li}_1(-\omega)\log(-\omega)}{1+\omega}d\omega=\\
&=&\text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)\log(-\omega) + 2\int \text{Li}_1(-\omega)d\text{Li}_2(1+\omega)=\\
&=&\text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)\log(-\omega)+2\text{Li}_1(-\omega)\text{Li}_2(1+\omega) + 2\int \frac{\text{Li}_2(1+\omega)}{1+\omega}d\omega=\\
&=&\text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)\log(-\omega)+2\text{Li}_1(-\omega)\text{Li}_2(1+\omega) + \text{Li}_3(1+\omega).
\end{eqnarray}
Thus we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=&\log^2(1-i)\log \omega +2\log(1-i) \text{Li}_2(-\omega) +\\
&&+\text{Li}_1^2(-\omega)\log(-\omega)+2\text{Li}_1(-\omega)\text{Li}_2(1+\omega) + \text{Li}_3(1+\omega)
\end{eqnarray}

Now, using the same change of variable in $\mathcal I_3$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_3 &=&  \int \frac{\left[\log(1+i)+\log(1-i\omega)\right]^2}{\omega}d\omega=\\
&=&\log^2(1+i)\log \omega +2\log(1+i) \text{Li}_2(i\omega) +\underbrace{\int\frac{\text{Li}_1^2(i\omega)}{\omega}d\omega}_{\mathcal B(\omega)}.
\end{eqnarray}
Observe that
$$\mathcal B(\omega) = i\mathcal A(-i\omega).$$
Thus we can use the results already obtained to get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_3 &=& \log^2(1+i)\log \omega +2\log(1+i) \text{Li}_2(i\omega) +\\
&&+i\text{Li}_1^2(i\omega)\log(i\omega)+2i\text{Li}_1(i\omega)\text{Li}_2(1-i\omega) + i\text{Li}_3(1-i\omega)
\end{eqnarray}

Again the same change on variables yields, for $\mathcal I_2$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_2 &=& \int\frac{[\log(1-i)+\log(1+\omega)][\log(1+i)+\log(1-i\omega)}{\omega}d\omega=\\
&=& \log 2 \log \omega + \log(i-1)\text{Li}_2(i\omega)+\\
&&+\log(i+1)\text{Li}_2(-\omega)+\underbrace{\int\frac{\log(1-i\omega)\log(1+\omega)}{\omega}d\omega}_{\mathcal C}.
\end{eqnarray}
$\mathcal C$ is the trickiest part. Haven't completed it yet.

Comment: I get a idea from your answer.

Comment: @LiTaichi good. If I have more time, I'll try developing also the rest of the integral. I think then, there should be a way to connect polylogarithm special values to $G$ and $\zeta(\cdot)$.

Comment: But I can't solve the four integrations, too.

Comment: @LiTaichi you mean the four in your new edit?

Comment: Yes,they are also difficult.

Comment: Do you have some idea?

Comment: @LiTaichi not really, for now. But I think I can get some more "juice" out of my three, instead; don't you think it's possible? I'm also correcting some typos and some mistakes...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90155/discussion-between-litaichi-and-matteo).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution similar to FDP's, by trying to build a relation with a similar integral we have:
$$I=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx,\:J=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$

$$I+J=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1-x^2\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$I+J=\frac{1}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\ln ^3\left(2\right)$$
That last integral can be computed easily if one considers the algebraic identity $ab=\frac{1}{4}\left(a+b\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}\left(a-b\right)^2$.

---

$$I-J=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx+\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)}{1+x}\:dx-2\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx}_{N}$$
$$-\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx-\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx+2\underbrace{\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx}_{K}$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-\frac{9}{4}\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x}\:dx$$
$$+2\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$$
$$=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x}\:dx-\frac{3}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)$$
$$=-2\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(x\right)\ln \left(1+x\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx-\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{x}dx-\frac{3}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)$$
$$=\frac{9}{32}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kH_{2k}}{k^2}-\frac{1}{2}\sum _{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^kH_k}{k^2}$$
$$=\frac{9}{32}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{23}{32}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}G+\frac{5}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)$$
$$I-J=\frac{21}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}G$$
The integral $N$ can be computed quite simply by considering the substitution $x=\frac{1}{1+x}$.

As for the integral $K$ can be found calculated in a similar fashion in the book *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series* page $\#98$.

---

We have:
\begin{alignat*}{4}
I & {}+{}  & J & {}={}  \frac{1}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{1}{4}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\ln ^3\left(2\right) \\
 I & {}-{}  &  J & {}={}   \frac{21}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{3}{8}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-\frac{\pi }{2}G \\
\end{alignat*}

---

So we conclude that:
$$I=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1-x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=\frac{11}{16}\zeta \left(3\right)-\frac{5}{16}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)-\frac{\pi }{4}G+\frac{1}{12}\ln ^3\left(2\right)$$
$$J=\int _0^1\frac{x\ln \left(1+x\right)\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=-\frac{5}{8}\zeta \left(3\right)+\frac{1}{16}\ln \left(2\right)\zeta \left(2\right)+\frac{\pi }{4}G+\frac{1}{12}\ln ^3\left(2\right)$$